# why doesnt my formatting work in my wisiwig editor?

Tags: formatting

I am trying to format my post with extra blank lines. But for some reason they dont get reflected when i save it? But the underline etc work fine

Any idea how to sort this problem

Answer (score 2):

The Visual editor is behaving as-configured.

You will either need to pass a custom configuration setting to tell TinyMCE not to ignore multiple line-breaks, or else you will need to use the HTML editor if you want to add line-breaks in the manner that you're currently using.

Answer (score -1):

The WordPress visual editor automatically removes extra blank lines and spaces. An easy way around this is to use the following code in the HTML editor:

`<p style="text-align: left;"></p>`

This will preserve the spacing even when you return to the visual editor.

Comment: `align` stopped being acceptable in 1998. ;) Inserting a class to the element above the empty space or `<br>` is much better.

Comment: @toscho Unfortunately extra `<br />`s are also removed by the WordPress visual editor. And in lieu of using an apparently ancient `align` property, `<p style="text-align: left;"></p>` would be more appropriate.